# How can I create a template of Word with different odd and even pages

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

I am trying to create a template with a text box on top of each page (not in the header). I need the text box to be aligned differently on even and odd pages.

Is this possible, and how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft *Word* has templates for [booklet format](https://create.microsoft.com/en-us/search?query=booklet), i.e., a document folded in half, with different alignment on facing pages. However, those existing templates seem to be too complex and specific for most needs, so you can [create your own template](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-template-86a1d089-5ae2-4d53-9042-1191bce57deb).

First, start a new document and set its format as desired. For example:

- In *File > Layout >  Margins tab*, change the setting for Multiple pages to Book fold.
- Increase the value of *Gutter* as needed for the inside fold for binding.
- When printing, select *double-sided*, if you wish.

Then, [save this (blank) document as a template](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-template-86a1d089-5ae2-4d53-9042-1191bce57deb).

- Click*Click File > Save As*.
- Select *Word Template* from the *Save as type* list.
- Give the template a useful name, such as "HershyS Booklet".
- Click *Save* button. In *Explorer*, browse to *Custom Office Templates* folder in *My Documents*, and you should see that template, available for your next use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am specifically looking to include a text box in the body area of the pages. Can this be done in a template?

Answer (score 0):

### There are two complementary features in Word for this: Different Odd and Even Headers/Footers and Mirror Margins. "Text Boxes," as such do not respond to even and odd, though.

**Different Even and Odd Headers/Footers**

Here is [my writing on this feature](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Odd_and_Even) in my chapter on Sections.
The control is there in the Contextual Tab for Headers and Footers (it appears when you are editing a header or footer). This setting applies to both headers and footers.

[image: Header & Footer Tab]

**Mirror Margins**

This is a setting under the Layout tab and allows you to have a wider margin on the side of even/odd pages. This could also be simulated using text boxes or frames in the headers that extend through the entire page.

**Template**

In Word jargon, *"template"* has a special meaning. While it can be a model or example, in Word it means a file saved as a .dotx or .dotm file type. Here is my chapter on [Templates in Microsoft Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm).

**Text Boxes**

Expand a bit on what you mean by text box. You can have a box/border in the background in your headers that could be typed in/over in your page. You could use a style with a [Frame](https://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#sidebars) to start pages. You would want that style to also have the paragraph formatting of Page Break Before.

You could save two Text Boxes, one for left and one for right as Text Box Building Blocks. You would be able to [create keyboard shortcuts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330) to insert them if you wanted. This is the kind of Text Box you get under Insert > Text Box. It cannot be a part of a page layout, it is an element that goes on a page.

What is it you want these text boxes for? What is the purpose?

Word does not really understand or get the concept of pages on a basic level. See [Word Doesn't Know What a Page Is](https://wordmvp.com/Mac/PagesInWord.html) by Word MVP Daiya Mitchell.

Comment: I am specifically looking to have text boxes in the body text area. I am already familiar with margins and headers/footers

Comment: Expand on what you mean by "text box." A border? A formfield? People use the term "text box" to describe all sorts of things. Word does not really understand pages. https://wordmvp.com/Mac/PagesInWord.html You can have Frames as a part of paragraph styles and you could use different ones for left and right pages but this is not simple. https://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#sidebars

Comment: to be specific. I would like to have every page start with block text in the upper right hand or upper left hand corner of the page. I need this text to be unique to each page, and I want the body text to flow around it. I can do this by drawing a text box on each page and align it, but this would be very cumbersome as I am planning a large document (about 100 pages)

Comment: Is the text to go in this anywhere else on the page? If so, you could put it in the header and use a StyleRef field. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF Again, you can set up and save model text boxes as building blocks. You can set a Frame as part of a style definition. Frames are old technology, predating text boxes but can be very useful. Text can flow around a Text Box or a Frame. Othewise, you may want to look at Publisher, InDesign, or even PowerPoint.